# Broadcast not getting called with AlarmManager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm having trouble with the broadcast message the alarm manager should send.
This is my code:

```
case Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED:
                long repeatInterval = 10*1000;
                long triggerTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + repeatInterval;
                AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                if(manager != null){
                    Intent in = new Intent(context, AppReceiver.class);
                    in.setAction("haz");
                    PendingIntent inte = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 500, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);



                    manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, triggerTime, repeatInterval, inte);
                }
                break;
```

That's being triggered correctly with the action boot completed broadcast message, but that piece of code if I'm right should call the app receiver with the "haz" action, but that's not being called, ever. 
I've tried to create a service but that's also not being called.

Anyone has any clue for what I have to do?

Comment: You cannot have a repeat interval that short. Beyond that, confirm that your receiver is registered in the manifest, and then examine Logcat to see if there are any particular problems being reported.

Comment: The receiver was registered in manifest just as Arwy has posted, but still not working... Also, no error is being reported in Logcat... It's just not being called ever.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <receiver android:name=".YourReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
       <!-- check properly boot intent syntax for manifest file -->
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Comment: I had that almost the same, the only thing that was different is the android:priority tag, is that important?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution thanks to CommonsWare reply to my question. The answer was to have another receiver separately probably because android can't handle fast repetitions. Mine wasn't going to be that short in the end, it was for testing purposes only, but having two receivers and to call the second one with the repetitions was the answer. Thank you both @CommonsWare and @Arwy Shelke for your time and responses!!